# My package added to shadow-fixed repository with bloom is installed into a wrong path

Tags: ros, buildfarm, ros-kinetic, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Environment

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- ROS distro: Kinetic
- bloom version: 0.6.7
- catkin_pkg version: 0.4.9
- rosdep version: 0.12.2
- rosdistro version: 0.6.9
- vcstools version: 0.1.40

### What I'm working on

I've just added my created package `timed_roslaunch` into shadow-fixed repository according to [bloom turorial](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease).

Recently merged `rosdistro/kinetic/distribution.yaml`related to `timed_roslaunch` is [here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/19405/files).

I firstly tested `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-timed-roslaunch` after switching repository from `ros` to `ros-shadow-fixed` by referring to [ShadowRepository Wiki Page](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) and the install command was successfully completed.

### What's wrong

However, the package files were installed into directly under `/` not `opt/ros/kinetic/`

For example, launch files in `gazebo_ros` are installed as the following directory configuration.

- /

  - opt/

    - ros/

      - kinetic/

        - share/

          - gazebo_ros/

            - launch/

On the other hand, in case of `timed_roslaunch`, launch files are installed as follows.

- /

  - launch/

Also, I directly download and checked deb package named `ros-kinetic-timed-roslaunch_0.1.1-3xenial-20181107-003648-0800_amd64.deb` from [ros-shadow-fixed repository](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-timed-roslaunch/) to find the launch directory is already set ot just under root `/`.

This causes any ros commands such as `roscd`, `roslaunch` and so on cannot find `timed_roslaunch` even after `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`

I want to change the install directory from `/` to `opt/ros/kinetic/` same as `gazebo_ros`.

Do I have to change anything when I use bloom? Does anyone know how can it be fixed?

### Reference

- https://github.com/MoriKen254/timed_roslaunch
- https://github.com/MoriKen254/timed_roslaunch-release
- https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307927/my-package-added-to-shadow-fixed-repository-with-bloom-is-installed-into-a-wrong-path/) by [MoriKen254](https://answers.ros.org/users/38432/moriken254/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds like your CMake is installing files to the wrong location. Looking into your repository it seems you have short tried to fix the problem in this commit:: https://github.com/MoriKen254/timed_roslaunch/commit/6b98f7723d4d154298511a1845438d9a07a6eb3a

But since then you haven't released a new version yet (the commit is one after the 0.1.1 tag). Therefore I would suggest to create a release 0.1.2 and run bloom for that one. The new Debian package might already look better.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MoriKen254](https://answers.ros.org/users/38432/moriken254/) on 2018-11-08**:
Thank you so much. I didn't realize my fixing CMakeFile wasn't applied to 0.1.1. I released 0.1.2 n will let you know if it succeeds.
BTW I don't get yet why copying dir fails like https://github.com/MoriKen254/timed_roslaunch/commit/6b98f7723d4d154298511a1845438d9a07a6eb3a?diff=split before the fix

**Comment by [MoriKen254](https://answers.ros.org/users/38432/moriken254/) on 2018-11-09**:
Thank you! any problems mentioned here have been fixed!